# Apache URL rewrite rule and regex

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

probably my question duplicate with an other title but, I have read too many title and checked many times with google. So if it duplicates, I am sorry.

Now I have an URL:

```
www.mysite.com/profile.php
```

I am using this URL rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$    profile.php?username=$1 [NC,L]
```

And I can change my url like:

```
www.mysite.com/username
```

Then, I need to update my url with an other get parameter:

```
www.mysite.com/username/photos
```

At this part, I have an URL like:

```
www.mysite.com/profile.php?username=xxx&w=photo
```

I have tried this URL rule for the url for above:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$/?$    profile.php?username=$1&w=$2 [NC,L]
```

But It does not work. Please help.

Thank you very much.

-------UPDATE------

Now I can use profile.php which It should be. But other rewrite rules are broken. My current .htaccess file like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1&w=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^p/timeline timeline.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^p/notifications notifications.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first:

```
[A-Za-z0-9-_]
```

is not a correct regex because of unescaped hyphen between `9` and `_` in a character class that acts as a range between hex 39 and hex 5f. To fix this make sure to use hyphen at first or last position in a character class.

Correct rules will be:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1&w=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [QSA,L]
```

---

**Update:**

As per your updated question make sure to use generic rule after specific rule. So have your rules like this:

```
RewriteRule ^p/(notifications|timeline)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1&w=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/(.+)$    profile.php?username=$1&w=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)$    profile.php?username=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: It work but again I have a problem. When second get arguments is null, this rule does not work. I want to use **mysite.com/username** and **mysite.com/username/details** at the same time. So how many rules should I have?

Answer (score 0):

You can just have one rule if you want. I would also add the conditions so that it makes sure it's not a real directory or file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)?/?$ /profile.php?username=$1&w=$2 [NC,L]
```

In your PHP you will just have to check the `w` parameter to see if it's empty or not. If it's not, display the details also.